# Apple Books - Add chapter and page number to the Excerpt from when copying the quote

Tags: copy-paste, books

I copy and paste the content from the Apple Books to my notes from time to time. I would like to better document the reference.

Now when I copy and paste the content, the critique looks like the following

*"Excerpt From
Your Next Five Moves
Patrick Bet-David
This material may be protected by copyright."*

Which is

-Title of the book -Author

But is it possible to add the page number based on iBook and the chapter's name on the critique?

Something like

*"Excerpt From
P. 15, Chapter 1,
Your Next Five Moves,
Patrick Bet-David
This material may be protected by copyright."*

Would greatly appreciate any help at all, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you share instead of copying then you get date, chapter, page number etc. From there you can select all <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, copy <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and paste <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> wherever you like.

I have encountered very few books where "Printed Edition Page Numbers" (under View menu) can be enabled, so page number is kind of moot - it depends on reader window and font size.

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much! It works like magic, much appreciate your help :-)!